# Failed to sync Gradle project in Android Studio 1.4

Tags: java, android

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough space for object heap.
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
```

please tell me how to resolve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much do what it says -- in your project's directory, edit `gradle.properties`.  There should be a line similar to --

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

change those numbers to bigger numbers to increase the memory limit for gradle.  For example, the following seems to work well --

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Comment: i tried that one also but it didnt worked. My RAM size 2GB

Comment: You have 2G RAM total in your computer?

Comment: yes, i have only 2GB RAM and my HDD 40GB and my processor Dual Core

Comment: I am not sure 1.4 will run well at all on only 2GB.  It recommends 4G.